# C++ strlen error in Big C++

Tags: c++, string

I've been working through some of the programs in [Big C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471470635) and after I copied append.cpp, Eclipse was telling me `'strlen' was not declared in this scope` on line 8. I took a look online, and I thought it was because I had to include the `<cstring>` library, but that didn't solve it. What's wrong?

append.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

void append(char s[], int s_maxlength, const char t[])
{
    int i = strlen(s); // error occurs here
    int j = 0;
    while(t[j] != '\0' && i < s_maxlength)
    {
         s[i] = t[j];
         i++;
         j++; 
    }
    //Add zero terminator
    s[i] = '\0';
 }

int main()
{
    const int GREETING_MAXLENGTH = 10;
    char greeting[GREETING_MAXLENGTH + 1] = "Hello";
    char t[] = ", World!";
    append(greeting, GREETING_MAXLENGTH, t);
    cout << greeting << "\n";
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: [Compiles for me.](http://ideone.com/XsY2sF)

Comment: Should compile fine with <cstring> included: http://ideone.com/dkAVsG

Comment: Compiles for me on VS2010

Comment: Including `<cstring>` should fix it (and does for me). But why are you messing around with dangerous C-style string manipulation in C++?

Comment: @H2C03, I'm running this in Eclipse using g++. I tried including the <cstring> library, but I still received the same error.

Comment: Also, try to actually compile it. It's maybe just that the static analyzer in Eclipse is being dumb, but the compiler will run just fine (as it should).

Comment: "Big C++"? Never heard of that language.

Comment: @H2C03, I ran it in a different text editor and compiled it manually. It works now. Seems Eclipse just has a couple of issues...

Comment: Show us the actual source file that exhibits the problem. The code in your question doesn't have `#include <cstring>`. Add `#include <cstring>`, verify that the compiler complains, and copy-and-paste your exact source file, plus the exact error message, into your question.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, my apologies, I was referencing this book: http://www.amazon.com/Big-C-Cay-S-Horstmann/dp/0471470635

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I believe its a book, though never heard of it either

Comment: Just a note - void append(char s[], int s_maxlength, const char t[]) is bad practice - passing arrays using [] syntax is syntactically strange, and invokes some strange corners of the C++ language that many are not familiar with. If you must pass raw arrays around, the correct syntax is char*. If your book uses char name[] as function arguments, I strongly recommend getting a better book.

Comment: @Stewart, gotcha. I think I'll toss this book aside and go with a different one

Comment: Have a look at this list for recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1025391

Comment: That it compiles for one compiler does not actually prove anything regarding other compilers in the case of missing headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including the `<cstring>` header should solve (should have solved) the issue. My suspicion was correct: it was only Eclipse being dumb, it gave you a false positive.

In cases like this, don't believe the IDE! Always try to compile the source text - if the compiler accepts it, then the static analysis tool in the IDE was wrong.